# Get [n] element in this array, in .php?

Tags: sql, arrays

[tldr] How to get nth element of a .php array; is a novice [tldr]

How do i get any element in this array? I am having trouble understanding .php arrays for some reason, i dont know where the index is, and how to "specify it", and googling hasn't helped. Alot of this code was copy pasted as well.

In qrFile1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "********";
$username = "*************";
$password = "********************";
$dbname = "***************";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else {
    echo "Succcccessssful concection ";
}



// sql for dispplayying info
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, message FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id:" . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "- email " . $row["email"]. " -message " . $row["message"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking. But, you have code specifying an associative array $row = $result->fetch_assoc(). The elements are accessed by name correctly in your code $row["id"].

If you would like an array that you can access using an index. Use $row = $result->fetch_array() and access the elements like this: $row[0] etc.

Comment: So then if i made the statement: echo $row[0]  that would display the elements of the first row? and would i do that after the if($row = $result ->fetch_accoc()) line right?

Comment: That would print the first column value of one row, yes.

Comment: How would i get the second or the third column value of one row then?